# Can I compare performance between sql servers?

Tags: sql-server, performance-testing, sqlperformance, sql-server-profiler

I want to know if new code is faster or slower than the current code.  I can use profiler to trace both the new code and old code, but it is easiest to do this on different servers, and even if I could do it on the same server, I'd have a significant number of other people using that server at the same which affects performance.  Can I compare Reads and CPU to do an apples-to-apples comparison?  Or will these values depend on the underlying hardware?  Obviously I can't do anything with Duration information.  Any other trace columns I should look at?

Comment: Of course you can compare on a different server BUT your results MAY be less accurate (or even completely not comparable). _Code_ is not an entity that live in isolation: it's executed on a specific server (with a specific sw & hw configuration) and it's used in a specific way. The same code called in an isolated test environment and in production with 1M+ concurrent users may behave in a completely different way. Concurrency also does not affect just _your_ code but also HW (disk access and all other shared resources) and possibly sw.

Comment: Yes, you can and should start benchmarking on a separate non-production machine (better if with the same hw/sw configuration), at first in a controlled isolated test environment, then to refine your results you should try to reproduce real production environment (workload, hw, accesses). But the final word (when you're reasonably sure that your new code works as expected and performance are reasonably better) you MUST check with production server (possibly redirecting only _some_ traffic if you have a load balancer). After few days you can compare the live results of the "old" and the "new"

Comment: And a final word about optimization. Often you need to find a compromise: better average response, better response in the worst (but not frequent) case, better best case response (if frequent enough) and so on (or most probably a balance between them all). All these measures are affected by hw/sw/usage patterns. To reproduce them in a test environment isn't an easy task (don't underestimate this).